# How to stop C# form from rendering the controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, overriding, paint

I am using `BufferedGraphics` to redraw my form. I wish to redraw the form's controls all by myself, so I can draw lines wherever I want while I can still use the Form Designer to align my controls.

I've tried `SuspendLayout` but it make no use here.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BufferedGraphicsContext context;
    BufferedGraphics grafx;
    PictureBox pic1, pic2;
    public Form1()
    {
        SetStyle((ControlStyles)(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint), true);
        InitializeComponent();
        //Add picturebox
        pic1 = new PictureBox();
        pic1.BackColor = Color.Black;
        pic1.SetBounds(50, 50, 100, 50);
        Controls.Add(pic1);
        pic2 = new PictureBox();
        pic2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        pic2.SetBounds(75, 50, 50, 100);
        Controls.Add(pic2);
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        context = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
        context.MaximumBuffer = new Size(Width, Height);
        grafx = context.Allocate(CreateGraphics(), new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height));
    }
    public override void Refresh() { }
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) { }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = grafx.Graphics;
        g.Clear(BackColor);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
            c.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(c.Left, c.Top, c.Width, c.Height));
        g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 4), 0, 0, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
        grafx.Render(Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle));
    }
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        context.MaximumBuffer = new Size(this.Width, this.Height);
        if (grafx != null)
        {
            grafx.Dispose();
            grafx = null;
        }
        grafx = context.Allocate(this.CreateGraphics(), new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height));
        base.Refresh();
    }
}
```

I need the line to be drawn at the top of the controls (picturebox), but the code turns out to be drawn below the controls.

Comment: i would call `SetStyle` earlier than `Load`.

Comment: sorry, let me edit it.

Comment: @J3soon Interesting question btw...I could be wrong but I really believe you could get the coordinates of a control and simply draw a line where you want using those coordinates as your reference point. In short I'm saying I don't think you need to redraw them yourself but I think it's neat you are

Comment: I found a link where someone was trying to do what you are here --> http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/301044/Drawing-line-above-all-the-controls-in-the-form

Comment: You can not use form paint to draw on top of the pic boxes. You can draw **only** where there are no controls.

Comment: @waltmagic Thanks a lot! But I wish to draw lines, circles and images, and since `Grpahics` supports a bunch of drawing functions, like gradient and others, I prefer to draw with it.

Comment: @waltmagic I'm thinking there's maybe a way to override the Form's drawcontrol function. I overrided `Refresh` `OnPaintBackground` and `OnPaint` but the form still renders the controls.

Comment: @J3soon I am very interested to see a solution or answer to your question because this is something I never really thought to do but I want to know now...btw I think a WPF project instead of a windows form makes things like this much easier to do